# Creating A Soundboard in C# Visual Studio Sound Control Panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been working on a fun little project wich is a SoundBoard & now I've stumbled on to a little issue, I get everything to work flawlessly, the only thing is that I really don't know how to add a Volume Control Bar since the volume in my software is really loud (it might be called a Volume Control Button). In any case, it's one of those where you can control the sound volume of the software, essentially its like a music player.

Does anyone know what I could try looking for?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
        player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

This is basically the code for every button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Slider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.110).aspx) control. You listen to the `ValueChanged` event and change the volume appropriately.

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged (object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var slider   = sender as Slider;
    double value = slider.Value;
    // assuming media is some sort of media control object
    media.SetVolume (value);
}
```

You can set the maximum value of the slider, depending on your maximum volume. Or just do `(value/slider.Maximum)` to get the slider position as a percent value, then you could do `volume = (value/slider.Maximum) * max_volume` to set the volume as a percentage of the maximum.

**EDIT:** The `SoundPlayer` class does not support setting the volume, but `SoundEffectInstance` does. Please refer to the [SoundEffectInstance MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940201.aspx) for more information. 
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found this wich helped me a bit better, someone else might benefit from this aswell.
[Occurs when the Value property of a track bar changes, either by movement of the scroll box or by manipulation in code.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)